# Facebook shared links not opening (Not redirecting correctly)

Tags: facebook, social-networking

I have been in a problem and after hours of searching find nothing useful to counter it. I have a website, and that website has RSS feed attached to facebook page. As I post the content to website it also appears on facebook page. But I have people complaining on my page that my posts don't open when they click the link to read the details. Since I am a Chrome user and didn't notice this happening for months. But as I checked it through firefox and Internet Explorer, I found the links shared actually don't open with these browswers. They only work in Chrome, means they are properly redirected in chrome browser and not in firefox and IE. Whenever I click on links of posts on my page through IE or firefox the url does not simply redirect to my website and I get to see nothing as if I am not connecting to Internet. When examining URL I see this:

http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F112NVO9&h=EAQHDgTUv&s=1

Which shows that facebook is not redirecting the links properly. 
Moreover I also use link shortening service bit.ly to shorten my shared links. I have checked same problem exists even if I don't shorten my links. And I checked I am not alone, even the tech giant website mashable.com links also don't open in IE and FF from facebook, they only open in Chrome.

From mobile phone the links don't open (redirected properly) even in chrome.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue? Nothing much is written about it on Internet as no once has faced this problem.

P.S: I have checked from different systems, the problem persists.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would be more nice, if you mention What is your Actual Link and where is it going. Normally this happens due to Virus.

I have clicked the Above Link and It Followed me to http://www.pakistanplacement.com/2013/06/jobs-in-oracle-corporation-territory.html Blogger page.

This worked same on IE, Mozilla and Chrome.

If you are viewing different Results on Different Browser, Your Browser might be victim of Adware. So Try to scan your Computer and check the Add-Ons installed in browser.

Hope it helps,
John Bhatt

Answer (score 0):

I just found this http://goo.gl/WA2YyE url on a www.facebook.com/RecruiterPk and it redirects me to http://www.recruiter.com.pk/job/ and works absoltly fine.